# RAILS_ENV set but Rails.env is different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I think I've exhausted all I could find to try and actually set the environment for my rails app.

In .htaccess

```
RailsEnv production (produces a 500 server error)
```

In environment.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production' #does not set RAILS_ENV
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production' #sets RAILS_ENV to 'production', but Rails.env stays at 'development'
```

I'm using bluehost...but everything's been working just fine up until yesterday...I don't think I made any changes...

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention that it's Rails v2

Also, depending on where I set the RAILS_ENV variable in environment.rb, I get errors.  If I put it in the place where I'm told it's supposed to be, I get the error:

> [Tue Jul 26 11:42:20 2011] [warn] [client x.x.x.x]
>   (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from
>   FastCGI server
>   [Tue Jul 26 11:42:20 2011] [error] [client
>   x.x.x.x] Premature end of script headers: dispatch.fcgi

```
# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.11' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "production" unless (File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) =~ /MyProductionFolder/).nil?
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/usr/ruby/gems'
```

If I put it AFTER the boot join, the variable gets set but the actual environment doesn't change.

```
# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.11' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "production" unless (File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) =~ /MyProductionFolder/).nil?
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/usr/ruby/gems'
```

EDIT #3: Inspecting ENV['RAILS_ENV'], I see "production", but when inspecting RAILS_ENV directly, I see "development".

Comment: may be you host has changed something, upgraded rails or something else.

Comment: Maybe but as expected they're pushing the excuse on me and telling me to "check the rails forums"

Comment: Have you tried setting `Rails.env = 'production'` in your environment.rb file to see what happens?

Comment: It's Rails version 2.  This gives me an application error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a whole whack of garbage files and folders lying around from earlier failed attempts at creating the app.  I had nested an app in a folder called 'generate' within my main app (guess how THAT happened :S (nub-ness)). Among other things, empty cgi-bin folders lying around and an empty dispatch.fcgi file in my public directory.  I have NO IDEA how that got there, I swear.

Anyways, long story short the solution was to compare my app directory to a fresh rails app and delete all the cruft.  I also copied over the brand-new dispatch files from the new app to my current app and I took out all comments and superfluous line breaks from my database.yml file.  Character and file formatting might have also played a part somewhere (my bluehost tech support said).  Also, I commented out "AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi" from my .htaccess - I had done this before to no effect...so I'm guessing THAT coupled with spring cleaning fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [passenger docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#RailsBaseURI), RailsEnv works in .htaccess only if AllowOverride Options is set. Have you checked if that's the case?